# Install headless version linux for old NAS system

Tags: linux, nas, headless

I have a NAS storage (WD MyBook, the old one [https://images.anandtech.com/doci/4952/mybook_photo.JPG]) and I want to change the HDD for a new one. Currently it runs LinuxNAS, which appears to be some kind of on distro. The HW is really low standards but enough for the job.
Which distro should I use? I only need ssh, sftp, samba and ajax/nginx so it should do the work. The problem here is, the only I/O port of the nas is Ethernet. I can ssh into it, but that's it.

How do I install (or pre-install) such a distro? Should I first install it in antoher computer and then just swap it or should I just format the hdd and copy some files into it? I've read about the preseeded installations, but it says it is going to ask me also about the partitions, how do I answer it?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I would open up the enclosure, and look for a 3 or 4-pin header, which would be for a 3.3V TTL serial-port connection.  The serial port would be the console for the system.  Soldering may be necessary if no header is already installed.  BTW intelligent people (or people who want to at least appear intelligent) do not write *"gonna"* in place of "going to".

Comment: @sawdust thanks for the comment, I hope I now appear intelligent enough. So you are telling me there is no way to prepare the HDD in order to auto-install itself or to open a ssh channel in order to install it without having to get myself a serial card and spend more time figuring out how to make it run than actually changing the drive?

Comment: You don't need a *"serial card"*, but rather a USB-to-serial adapter, which can be less than US$2 if you don't mind waiting, e.g. www.aliexpress.com.  Having a serial console ensures that you have a fall-back capability in case of any install or boot failures, i.e. no bricked device.  SSH only works after a successful boot.  I wrote what I would do because you solicited *"any hints"*.  I don't understand your complaining about *'there is no way"* when I never stated anything like that.  If you think you can replace the HDD w/o a serial console, then go ahead and try.

Comment: Ok, I think I started with the wrong foot here. I was hoping that there was a way to copy some files or even some sort of pre-install linux with another computers help and then start the NAS and ssh into it to perform the final installation. Similar to a Raspberry but with another Hardware. That's it.
And yes, I felt kind of insulted with your comment but I should not have had it influence my answer.